# URL problems for Django Help system

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm implementing a Help system for the admin site of a Django app. The help texts are implemented as model objects in a separate app called admin-help. The admin site uses `Grappelli`.

The setup is as follows.

In my main `urls.py` I have:

```
(r'^admin-help/', include('admin-help.urls')),
```

This is located before the default `admin` urls and `Grappelli` urls.

In `urls.py` for the `admin-help` app I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^admin-help/list-modelXYZ', 'admin-help.views.list-modelXYZ'),
    ...
)
```

My plan was to pull the help pages in via AJAX calls from the admin pages. So, I modified one particular admin template to include a HELP button with an `onclick` handler to call a Javascript function that passes a topic:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="showHelp('list_modelXYZ')" class="grp-state-focus">Help</a>
</li>
```

The `showHelp()` function performs the AJAX call passing the requested topic as part of the requested url:

```
function showHelp(topic) {
  grp.jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/admin-help/' + topic,
    success: function(html) {
      grp.jQuery('#help-content-area').html(html);
      grp.jQuery('#help-frame').show();
    }
  });
}
```

Within the admin-help app I have in my `views.py`:

```
def list_modelXYZ():
  return HttpResponse("Hello world!")
```

When I click the help button I get a 404 with the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin-help/list_modelXYZ
```

Why do I get a 404 on this? I'm not a Django Jedi and hopefully someone can point out my mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include your urls under the "admin-help" prefix,

```
(r'^admin-help/', include('admin-help.urls')),
```

then that "roots" those URLs under that prefix.
See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs
That means the prefix "admin-help" is already "processed" when it reaches your subhandler. The issue is that your subhandler is repeating the prefix:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^admin-help/list-modelXYZ', 'admin-help.views.list-modelXYZ'),
    ...
)
```

so you're matching "admin-help/admin-help/list-modelXYZ".
Just remove the prefix from your sub urls and you'll get what you're after:

admin-help/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^list-modelXYZ', 'admin-help.views.list-modelXYZ'),
    ...
)
```

If you have a lot of those, you can shortcut to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('admin-help.views',
    ...
    url(r'^list-modelXYZ', 'list-modelXYZ'),
    url(r'^more$', 'something_else'),
    ...
)
```

P.S.: "admin-help" is not a good name for a module, because "-" is the "minus" operator. "import admin-help" will get you a SyntaxError. "help" isn't good either (built-in function), I suggest "adminhelp". :-)

Answer (score 1):

The urlconf expects `list-modelXYZ`

```
url(r'^admin-help/list-modelXYZ', 'admin-help.views.list-modelXYZ'),
```

whiles you was accessing `list_modelXYZ` (note the underscore)

```
http://localhost:8080/admin-help/list_modelXYZ
```

Typo?

Also `'admin-help.views.list-modelXYZ'` inside urlconf seems should be `'admin_help.views.list_modelXYZ'`

Furthermore, there are two `^admin-help` in two urls.py files...

Comment: @Roger check your main urls.py, it already contains `^admin-help`. But in sub urls.py there is another `^admin-help`...